# how to change device id (google smart home action)

Tags: custom-action, google-smart-home, google-assistant

this might sound like a weird question, but is it possible to change the id of a device?
The unique id that i was using will desapear in my system source so i would like to change it.

I noticed that if a change the ids that are returned by the sync request the users will loose their customization in google home (the name of the device if they changed it and the associated room)

I would like to change it without loosing that.

Answer (score 0):

The [device ID](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/sync) is the string that identifies the device. There is no way to change.

> The ID of the device in the developer's cloud. This must be unique for the user and for the developer, as in cases of sharing we may use this to dedupe multiple views of the same device. It should be immutable for the device; if it changes, the Assistant will treat it as a new device.

If it is going to change in some source, you should find a way to continue the value through some sort of proxy.